# On checked - adding image instead of checkbox (Angular 4/Ionic 3)

Tags: javascript, css, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm trying to replace the checkbox with an image. This image will change based on css class whether or not it's checked. Adding a class doesn't work on change of checked because it changes all of the icons in the column. I'm using `ion-checkbox` for my checkbox. Doing `ion-checkbox:checked` does not work either in css.

**A look at the images below** I would like to replace the pin icon with the checkbox and when it's **checked the class changes the icon to a red color and changes one of them, not all.**

**HTML**

```
<tr *ngFor="let object of array">
  <td>
     <fa name="map-marker" [ngClass]="pinIcon ? 'unclick-pin' : 'click-pin'"></fa>
     <ion-checkbox (ionChange)="selectTwo(object, $event.checked)"></ion-checkbox>
  </td>
</tr>
```

**TS**

```
selectTwo(object, isChecked: boolean){
    this.pinIcon = !this.pinIcon;
}
```

[image: before] .   [image: after]

Comment: I don't understand this part "Adding a class doesn't work on change of checked because it changes all of the icons in the column". What do you mean by that?

Comment: Let's say I click on one of the icons (aka supposed to be checking one of the checkboxes, the other rows with the same column - same icon will change because the value is associated with the on click of the icon change and not the checked change)

Comment: can you reproduce this issue in https://stackblitz.com/ ? it is way more easier to understand. I don't understand your requirement at all. At least can you provide some images showing actual result ?

Comment: Adding images now, sorry about that

Comment: Hi can you add the markup for other checkboxes as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue with your code is, you are using single variable for all checkbox, and on ionChange you are changing that variable , so it will change all the checkbox.

Here it is, Change your code as below and it will work

> Template side :

```
<tr *ngFor="let object of array">
  <td>
     <fa name="map-marker" [ngClass]="object.pinIcon ? 'unclick-pin' : 'click-pin'"></fa>
     <ion-checkbox (ionChange)="selectTwo(object, $event.checked)"></ion-checkbox>
  </td>
</tr>
```

> Component side :

```
selectTwo(object, isChecked: boolean){
    object.pinIcon = isChecked;
}
```